# Volley API calling simplified solutions is needed, Call all APIs from a single method

Tags: android, android-volley

This is a simple Volley Api listener, how can every API from my project can be called from the single Api calling method. i have around 40 other similar APIs in a single project , i am tired of writing same block of code again and again. does anyone have idea  how to do it ??
==> i have heard making callbacks is a solution but i want the exact way to handle it.

```
  private void reservationCancelAPIExecute(String reservation_id) {

        CustomProgressBarDialog.progressDialog = CustomProgressBarDialog.showProgressDialog(mcontext);
        if (visible) CustomProgressBarDialog.progressDialog.show();

        final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();


        params.put("user_id", user_ID);
        params.put("reservation_id", reservation_id);

        Log.e("Parameters", params.toString());

        String REquestUrl = Config.APP_BASE_URL + Config.API_RESERVATION_CANCEL;

        StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REquestUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String responseObject) {
                        String newResponse = responseObject;
                        CustomProgressBarDialog.progressDialog.dismiss();

                        if (responseObject.contains("Ã¯Â»Â¿")) {
                            newResponse = newResponse.substring(newResponse.indexOf("{"));
                        }

                        try {
                            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(newResponse);
                            boolean error = response.getBoolean("error");
                            if (!error) {
                                CustomProgressBarDialog.progressDialog.dismiss();
                                session.createReservationByUser(DBTableFields.RESERVATION_STATE_CANCELLED);
                                session.createReservationByUser(DBTableFields.RESERVATION_STATE_NEW);
                                //EApplication.getInstance().showToastMessageFunction(response.getString("message"));
                               /* session.clearPickUPDropOffLocationAddress();*/
                                EApplication.getInstance().setPreviousReservationStatus(false);
                               /* reservationCancelSuccessDialog();*/
                                if (isAdded()) {
                                    EApplication.getInstance().showToastMessageFunction(getResources().getString(R.string.canceled_reservation));
                                }
                                //Toast.makeText(mcontext, getResources().getString(R.string.canceled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            } else

                            {
                                EApplication.getInstance().showToastMessageFunction("" + response.getString("message"));
                                CustomProgressBarDialog.progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            CustomProgressBarDialog.progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if(isAdded())
                EApplication.getInstance().showToastMessageFunction(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_availeble));
                VolleyLog.d("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                CustomProgressBarDialog.progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        }) {
            @Override

            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Request.Priority getPriority() {
                return Request.Priority.HIGH;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            /*headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");*/
                String current_language = session.getAppLanguage();
                Log.i("current_language", current_language);
                if (current_language.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LANG_ENG)) {
                    language = "en";
                }
                if (current_language.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LANG_THAI)) {
                    language = "np";
                }
                headers.put("lang", language);
                return headers;
            }
        };
        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                20000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        EApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, "high");
    }
```

and the Config file consists,, ie the list of APIs

```
package com.EddyCabLatest.application.constant;


public class Config {


    public static final String PRIVACY_POLICY_DRIVER_NEPALI =
            "<a href=https://www.eddycab.com/np/legal-2/privacy/drivers/";
    public static final String PRIVACY_POLICY_DRIVER_ENGLISH =
            "<a href=https://www.eddycab.com/en/legal/privacy/drivers/";
    public static final String PRIVACY_POLICY_PASSENGER_ENGLISH = "<a href=https://www.eddycab.com/en/legal/privacy/users/";
    public static final String PRIVACY_POLICY_PASSENGER_NEPALI =
            "<a href=https://www.eddycab.com/np/legal-2/privacy/users/";

    public static final String TERMS_DRIVER_NEPALI =
            "<a href=https://www.eddycab.com/np/legal-2/user-terms/";
    public static final String TERMS_DRIVER_ENGLISH =
            "<a href=https://www.eddycab.com/en/legal/terms-conditions/";


    public static final String GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY = "AIzaSyAi6qreeIcyoDDxtrcMnYqKwTMR064C4xc";//test


    public static final String GCM_SENDER_KEY = "1024195933443";
    public static final String APP_BASE_URL = "https://www.eddycab.com/API/public/";
    public static final String USER_REGISTER_URL = "api/users/register";
    public static final String USER_LOGIN_URL = "api/users/login";
    public static final String CREDIT_BONUS = "api/bananas/credit-and-bonus/";

    public static final String GET_NEW_RESERVATIONS = "api/reservations/new-reservations-by-driver/";
    public static final String USER_SET_BOOKING_URL = "api/reservations/set-booking";
    public static final String USER_GET_DRIVER_LOCATION_POST_URL = "api/reservations/get-driver-location";


    public static final String GET_BIDDING_RESULT_URL = "api/reservations/biddings/";
    public static final String GET_USER_PROFILE = "api/users/get-user-profile/";


    public static final String USER_RESERVATION_URL = "api/reservations/create";
    public static final String API_RESERVATION_CANCEL = "api/reservations/cancel-reservation/";
    public static final String USER_RESERVATION_RESPONSE_URL = "api/reservations/biddings/";
    public static final String UPDATE_FAV_HOME_URL = "api/users/set-favourite-home-place";
    public static final String UPDATE_FAV_WORK_URL = "api/users/set-favourite-work-place";
    public static final String EDIT_PROFILE = "api/users/edit-profile";
    public static final String UPDATE_USER_PROFILE_CHANGE_PROFILE_PIC = "api/users/set-profile-picture";


    public static final String DRIVER_BID_POST = "api/reservations/driverPostBid";
    public static final String DRIVER_RESERVATION_ASSIGN_POST = "api/reservations/reservation-assign";
    public static final String DRIVER_RESERVATION_IGNORE_POST = "api/reservations/reservation-ignore";
    public static final String DRIVER_RESERVATION_CANCEL_POST = "api/reservations/cancel-reservation-by-driver";
    public static final String DRIVER_DRIVER_PICKUP_PASSENGER_POST = "api/reservations/pickup-passenger";

    public static final String API_BIDDER_CANCEL_BY_USER = "api/reservations/cancel-bidder";


    public static final String USER_TRIP_HISTORY_URL = "api/reservations/user-trip-history/";
    public static final String Driver_BOOKING_HISTORY_URL = "api/reservations/driver-booking-history/";

    public static final String NEAREST_DRIVER_BY_LOCATION = "api/reservations/get-nearest-drivers";

    public static final String DRIVER_GET_QUITE_TIME_URL = "api/quietsetting/get-quiet-setting/";
    public static final String DRIVER_SET_QUITE_TIME_URL = "api/quietsetting/set-quiet-setting";

    public static final String SET_USER_LOCATION_POST_URL = "api/locations/set-location";

    public static final String GET_PUSH_NOTIFICATION_DRIVER = "api/reservations/send-reservation-push-notifications/";

    public static final String USER_FEEDBACK_RATING_URL = "api/feedbacks/user-feedback";
    public static final String SUPPORT_FEEDBACK_POST_URL = "api/support/insert-feedback";


    public static final String GET_MESSAGES_FROM_GCM_URL = "api/notifications/get-all-notifications/";

    public static final String DRIVER_JOB_COMPLETE_URL = "api/reservations/reservation-complete";
    public static final String DRIVER_PAY_VOUCHER_URL = "api/reservations/reservation-receipt";

    public static final String DELETE_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "api/notifications/remove-message/";
    public static final String DELETE_ALL_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "api/notifications/remove-user-messages/";
    public static final String USER_LOGOUT = "api/users/logout/";
    public static final String CHANGE_LANGUAGE = "api/users/set-language";
    public static final String LANG_ENG = "English";
    public static final String LANG_THAI = "Thai";
    public static final String USER_TYPE_DRIVER = "driver";
    public static final String USER_TYPE_USER = "user";
    public static final String USER_TYPE_USER_ID = "1";
    public static final String CALL_CENTER_NUMBER = "16600177711";
    public static final String Driver_TYPE_USER_ID = "2";
    public static final float CAMERA_FACTORY_UPDATE = 15;
    public static final String DEVICE_TYPE = "android";
    public static final long COUNTDOWN_TIME = 30000;


    public static final String FORGET_PASSWORD_SEND_MESSAGE = "api/users/forget-password/";
    public static final String CONFIRM_VERIFICATION_CODE = "api/users/verify-code";
    public static final String API_SET_NEW_PASSWORD = "api/users/set-new-password";
    public static final String RATE_USER_BY_DRIVER = "api/feedbacks/driver-feedback";
    public static final String URL_RESEEND_CODE_GET = "api/users/resend-code/";


    public static final String DRIVER_RECHARGE_HISTORY = "api/bananas/recharge-card-history/";
    public static final String RECHARGE_CARD = "api/bananas/recharge-card/";
    public static String DRIVER_JOB_COMPLETE_URL_call_center = "api/reservations/complete-callcenter-created-reservation";
}
```

Comment: do you have `lat_camera` & `long_camera` in your other 40 API calls??

Comment: @janaki gadhiya i have other apis like this  https://www.eddycab.com/API/public/api/reservations/biddings/3790   https://www.eddycab.com/API/public/api/reservations/biddings/3790

Comment: I have wrote a small wrapper project for Volley and Jackson libraries. If you want you can have a look here: https://github.com/akarapetsas/Monet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below approach:

**Create your own custom Interface for getting callback:**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Implement this listener for getting callback for UploadManager.doUpload()
 * method.
 * 
 * 
 */
public interface UploadListener {

    /**
     * On success upload, server response for given network upload task.
     * 
     * @param response
     */
    void onSuccessUploadResponse(JSONObject response);

    /**
     * On failed upload, server response for given network upload task.
     * 
     * @param error
     */
    void onErrorUploadResponse(Throwable error);
}
```

**Than create a Singleton class for network operations and to abstract out the volley code:**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Singleton class for network operations and to abstract out the volley
 * code.
 * 
 * @see <a
 *      href=" http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html">Volley</a>
 * 
 * 
 */
public class UploadManager {

    private static UploadManager uploadManager;
    private static RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    public static final int METHOD_POST = Request.Method.POST;
    public static final int METHOD_GET = Request.Method.GET;
    public static final int METHOD_PUT = Request.Method.PUT;
    public static final int METHOD_DELETE = Request.Method.DELETE;

    private UploadManager(Context context) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        // Start the queue
        mRequestQueue.start();
    }

    public static UploadManager getinstance(Context context) {
        if (uploadManager == null) {
            uploadManager = new UploadManager(context);
        }
        return uploadManager;
    }

    /**
     * Implement UploadManager.CallbackListener for getting callback for this
     * method.
     * 
     * @param url
     *            : url to be used for network call.
     * @param method
     *            : HTTP method type.
     * @param jsonRequest
     *            : JSON object to be sent
     * @param callbackListener
     *            : callback listener for getting success or error callback.
     */
    public void doUpload(String url, int method, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            final UploadListener callbackListener) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(method, url,
                jsonRequest, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        callbackListener.onSuccessUploadResponse(response);
                    };
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (null != error) {
                            callbackListener.onErrorUploadResponse(error
                                    .getCause());
                        }
                    }
                });
        mRequestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
}
```

And you can use the `doUpload();` method in all of your classes without writing volley code again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this https://github.com/gauravpolekar/androidnetworkmodule

You can use single method as well as its easy to call and distinguish multiple calls from a single class by using `requestCode`.